# knapsack with no values

Tags: python-3.x, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem

I am facing the next problem, I have a python dictionary like this:

```
total = 30

companies = {
 'a': 30,
 'b': 7,
 'c': 21,
 'd': 5,
 'e': 5,
  etc
}
```

What I am trying to do is group companies in a way that the numbers add up to a total. In this example the output I want would be:

```
group1 = {
 'a':30 
} 

group2 = {
 'c': 21,
 'b': 7
}

group3 = {
 'd': 5,
 'e': 5
}
```

If a value of a key in dictionary is > total then a group will be created containing only that key:value. For example if we would have

```
companies = {
 'a': 30,
 'b': 7,
 'c': 21,
 'd': 5,
 'e': 5,
 'f': 32
 etc
```

}

```
group1 = {
 'f':32
}
etc
```

I have searched for various ways of implementing this, best I have found would be Knapsack but this algorithm would take as input weight, value, only as int.
Also I found this interesting module:

https://developers.google.com/optimization/bin/knapsack

```
from __future__ import print_function
from ortools.algorithms import pywrapknapsack_solver

def main():
      # Create the solver.
      solver = pywrapknapsack_solver.KnapsackSolver(
      pywrapknapsack_solver.KnapsackSolver.
      KNAPSACK_DYNAMIC_PROGRAMMING_SOLVER,
      'test')

      weights = [[565, 406, 194, 130, 435, 367, 230, 315, 393,
          125, 670, 892, 600, 293, 712, 147, 421, 255]]
      capacities = [850]
      values = weights[0]
      solver.Init(values, weights, capacities)
      computed_value = solver.Solve()

      packed_items = [x for x in range(0, len(weights[0]))
                if solver.BestSolutionContains(x)]
      packed_weights = [weights[0][i] for i in packed_items]

      print("Packed items: ", packed_items)
      print("Packed weights: ", packed_weights)
      print("Total weight (same as total value): ", computed_value)
if __name__ == '__main__':
      main()
```

I have tried to modify this algorithm to work with a dictionary(especially with a string) but with no success.

Is there a better way to achieve this results?

Thank you,

Comment: Your group2 and group3 doesn't add up to 30. state the exact problem please.

Comment: Yes, group2 and group3 don't add up to 30 because our initials values are 30, 7, 21, 5, 5, 32. So 32 will go in group because its bigger than the max value, then 30 will go in another group because its equal to the max value. After this we will remain with the next values in our initial dictionary: 7, 21, 5, 5 now we have to group this in a way to be < max value, so we group 21 7 that would give us a closer total value to max value than grouping 21, 5, 5 that is over the max value. And that is why some of our groups don't add up.
Hope I was able to provide a explication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you are looking to minimize the overall number of groups that you are creating. This can be solved by iteratively creating a group with as much weight as possible in each iteration and then solving for the remaining items.

Note that I used a simple recursive implementation to solve the subset sum problem. You might want to use a more optimized framework if you operate on a larger data set.

```
# Group items into groups with max_weight
# Items with weight > max_weight get their own group
def create_groups(max_weight, items):
    # Will hold the assignment of each company to a group
    cur_group = 1
    groups = {}

    # Assign all companies with weight > max_weight
    for item, weight in items.items():
        if weight > max_weight:
            groups[item] = cur_group
            cur_group += 1

    # Cluster remaining items
    while 1:
        rem_items = {k: v for k, v in items.items() if not k in groups.keys()}
        if len(rem_items) == 0: break
        solution = solve_subset_sum(max_weight, rem_items)
        groups.update({k: cur_group for k in solution})
        cur_group += 1

    return groups


# Solve a subset sum problem 
def solve_subset_sum(max_weight, items):
    best_solution = []
    best_sum = 0
    for item, weight in items.items():
        if weight > max_weight: continue
        items_reduced = {k: v for k, v in items.items() if k != item}
        solution = solve_subset_sum(max_weight - weight, items_reduced)
        solution.append(item)
        solution_sum = sum([v for k, v in items.items() if k in solution])
        if solution_sum > best_sum:
            best_solution = solution
            best_sum = solution_sum

    return best_solution


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Input as specified by you
    total = 30
    companies = {
        'a': 30,
        'b': 7,
        'c': 21,
        'd': 5,
        'e': 5,
        'f': 32
    }

    # Test it
    groups = create_groups(total, companies)
    print(groups)
```

The code yields `{'f': 1, 'a': 2, 'c': 3, 'b': 3, 'e': 4, 'd': 4}` as a result. The format is `item_name: group_number`.

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was trying to do!